# Starting a machine causes windows 10 host machine to reboot

Tags: docker-machine

I'm running windows 10, Visual Studio 2017.

When running the following:

```
docker-machine ls
```

[image]

when attempting to start the machine:

```
docker-machine start default
```

[image]

**The host (physical machine) is forced to reboot!**

[image]

It does a clean reboot. **What am I doing wrong?**

How do I start the docker container without forcing my host to reboot?

Comment: what does this have to do with c# or visual studio?

Comment: my fault! it has nothing to do with it, i am using vs 2017 in order to package the container, at least i am hopeful that i will do that after i get docker working, ill remove the tag

Comment: Just FYI, you can copy and paste from the PowerShell window. That will make it easier to read (and search for) the logs.

Comment: Which version of docker are you using?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0ByqKtGmtuLzZQUJadDNoR3hFanM